# Is it bad practice for a class to be aware of its location in an array?

Tags: c#, arrays, class

Is it bad practice for a class to store its location within an array?

Similarly, is it bad practice for the collection to maintain each object's internal location?

If these are bad practices, what is a better way to have quick access to an object's location in an array or to maintain that position?

Comment: Why do you need this?  Provide a concrete example, and it may make it simpler for us to provide better alternatives...

Comment: This implies your class is a singleton, which may or may not be appropriate for your needs.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Generally, yes, it is a bad practice, for two reasons:

- Things that could be calculated should not be stored (e.g. storing an age and a DOB is a bad practice), and
- An object can belong to multiple collections at once, so it may not be clear which collection it should track.

There are two ways to address this problem:

- **Avoid it in the first place** - rather than passing around objects, pass around their indexes in the collection. When you need to access an object, apply the index to the collection. This way the index remains your "primary reference" to the object, so finding it out never becomes an issue, or
- **Calculate the positions as needed** - Keep a normal collection where objects do not keep an index. When you need to pair up objects and indexes, run a LINQ query that pairs them up temporarily; discard the results as soon as they are no longer needed.

Here is an example of a LINQ query to pair up objects and their indexes:

```
var objIndexPair = collection.
    Select((v, i) => new {
        Index = i
    ,   Object = v
    }).ToList();
```

Note that this approach does not make the class aware of its position in the collection. Rather, an anonymous class pairs up the object with its position in the collection, solving the problem of an object belonging to multiple collections.

Comment: I believe this is what I was looking for: _rather than passing around objects, pass around their indexes in the collection_. Though now I'm questioning the need for my objects to store their positions, since thinking on it, that's the purpose of the array...

Answer (score 9):

> Is it bad practice for a class to store its location within an array?

It depends, but often, yes.  The problem is that you're breaking the [single responsibility principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle) - the class not only has to maintain its state, but also its "position" within some other container.

This can lead to brittle designs, since there isn't a clear way of handling scenarios such as the class being in more than one container.  Also, moving an item becomes maintaining more code (changing the collection + the class internal representation), etc.

Comment: I agree with most of your answer.  I would love to see an example where the answer would be it's okay to do this.  I would think a class should never know anything about how it's used outside of itself (IE containers,etc.).  The container itself or another class (acting as a manager) would handle this "responsibility".

Comment: @Reed My thought was to have the object only _hold_ the position but not maintain it, instead maintaining that via the array or another class. I felt neither of those options was a good solution, though, hence the question. Thanks for your response!

Comment: @Josh If it's "holding but not maintaining", then it could get out of date, which is problematic.

Comment: @Geek It's very rarely a good idea - I won't say never, because just about every "rule" has an exception, though.

Comment: If the object's position is a property of the object, it can be convenient for the object store position.  E.g., having a grid puzzle's individual grid squares contain their positions, even though this duplicates information already encoded in positions within a two-dimensional array.  This is a bit ugly, but still, in my experience, more practical than trying to keep the coordinates truly separate from the elements.  Similarly, one might have an Object's ID be part of the object, even though the ID is already duplicated in the Dictionary referencing it.

Comment: Of course, both the scenarios I mention assume the ID and position are immutable.

Comment: @ReedCopsey Fair enough. We agree.  :)

Answer (score 0):

If an object your class is stored within another class - in this case an array - then it is the responsibility of that class to tell you where the object is stored within itself. If your object is guaranteed to be stored only withing ONE other class, then you might have a reference on the containing class in your contained class, but that is about it.

If you use collections, then this is precisely what you can do:

```
private class MyData
{
    // ...
}

private List<MyData> myDataList = new List<MyData>();

public void SomeMethod()
{
    MyData myData = ...;
    int position = myDataList.IndexOf(myData);
}
```

You should really never use arrays unless you absolutely have to. And if you can, convert your arrays which you get from some archaic legacy API to collections (i.e. lists), and just convert those back to arrays once you are done with them.

Comment: I disagree on the not-using-arrays remark; arrays are perfectly suitable in cases where you already know how many elements you need.  This comes up a lot when performing calculations using intermediate buffers, for instance.

Comment: You can have an `ArrayList` with a preinitialized size, too. And the moment you do need the tiniest bit more flexibility, you will be glad you did. I honestly do not see any advantage of Arrays over Collections.

Comment: The main advantage in my mind is in mapping the correct data structures to the concepts for which they are being used.  If you have a conceptual list of things where you want to Add and Remove items, then a List is a very natural choice.  If you have a conceptual fixed number of slots that you'd like to occupy, then an array makes more sense.  I do agree that arrays generally shouldn't be used purely for performance in cases where lists make more conceptual sense, as was often done in the past due to the lack of standard container support in old-school C.

Comment: In my experience, pretty much anywhere I had a "conceptual fixed number of slots", that number did change over time, and sooner or later, the "lets have it dynamic" requirement always came. I do see your point, though. So let's just agree to disagree and move on :)

Comment: @Jan Aside from the discussion of using arrays or not, IndexOf isn't an option for me in this case, as I will need the position of the objects fairly often, leading to IndexOf being fairly costly. Thank you for your response and the interesting discussion, though!

Comment: @Josh If you need fast lookups, perhaps you should use a map instead of a list or an array, then.

Comment: @Jan By map do you mean dictionary? I thought of that and implemented a class to both store a multidimensional array and the positions of the elements within the array, so I can both iterate over the array (guaranteeing that everything is positioned as it should be, since dictionary positions aren't) and use my own IndexOf(item) that pulls the item's location from the dictionary. I'm not sure if it's the best solution, but it certainly works well.

Comment: @Jan For a visual example: MyClass { Item[,]; Dictionary<Item, Position>; Item this[int, int]; // Returns item at row/column Location LocationOf(Item) { return _dictionary[item];} }

Comment: @Josh You can still use a Dictionary and have the keys sorted as you like, by using the `SortedDictionary`: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/f7fta44c.aspx

Comment: @Jan I...didn't know those existed! Hmm. I'm not sure if this works for what I'm looking at, but it's really good information to know! Thank you! If you'd like to chat further on the subject, my e-mail's in my profile.